# Dummy updates of Salesforce database records and execution governors

Tags: ajax, salesforce, dml

I need to trigger updates of a whole bunch of records in a Salesforce database without really updating any values. This is to make a few formulas to recalculate some fields.

Here's what I tried - a schedulable class (say I want it to run every night):

```
global class acmePortfolioDummyUpdate implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) 
    {
        for (Acme_Portfolio__c p : [Select Id From Acme_Portfolio__c]) {
            update(p);
        }
    }
}
```

update(p) is a DML statement and Salesforce limits the number of them to 150. In my case it's about a few thousands of records.

Also, I need to do this across many different portfolios. SF limits the number of scheduled classes to 10.

Any workaround for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  [Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm). You can schedule Your batch using schedulable class. Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't formulas recalculated each time You read them?

Edit: Comment don't have enought space.
I'm not guarantee this will compile (dont have access to org right now), but try sth like this:

```
global class batchClass implements Database.batchable<sObject>{ 
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id From Acme_Portfolio__c');    
    }   

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        update scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }   
}
```

And run this from system log:

```
Database.executeBatch(new batchClass());
```

Comment: Yep formulas do recalculate based on views. I'm guessing he means workflow field updates.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this with Batch Apex? I've read some documentation on it before but it's still quite mystical to me.

Comment: I'm not sure about the recalculation of formulas and workflow field updates. Let's just say that for the sake of it I need to trigger updates of bunch of custom objects.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, it's giving me an error though: Error: Compile Error: Type arguments must be supplied for parameterized type : Iterable<t> at line 3 column 12

Comment: Ups, this should be global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ in line 2, I have edited my answer

Comment: I've just thrown in the type on the first line too, you need that!

Comment: Error: Compile Error: batchClass: Class must implement the global interface method: Iterable<SOBJECT:Acme_Portfolio__c> start(Database.BatchableContext) from Database.Batchable<SOBJECT:Acme_Portfolio__c> at line 1 column 14

Comment: Seems that if You don't use generic sObject in type You have to return Iterbale not Query Locator. I have updated my answer, please check it now.